# Refactoring conditionals

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement, refactoring, conditional-statements

I've to output a text based on some conditionals, how can I refactor this to make it clear to understand and maintenance?

If the best option is replace with state, I'll need to create a class for each combinations of enums?

```
public enum CalcType {A, B, C, D}
public enum LicensingOption {HOME, PRO, ULTIMATE}

public void printHeader() {
    switch (calc) {
        case A:
            printHeaderX();
            break;
        case B:
            printHeaderY();
            break;
        default:
            printHeaderByLicensingOption();
    }
}

public void printHeaderByLicensingOption() {
    switch (license) {
        case PRO:
            printHeaderW();
            break;
        case HOME:
            printHeaderZ();
            break;
        case ULTIMATE:
            printHeaderA();
            break;
    }
}

public void printFooter() {
    if (calc.equals(CalcType.A))
        printFooterX();
    else
        printFooterByLicensingOption();
}

public void printFooterByLicensingOption() {
    switch (license){
        case PRO:
            printFooterW();
            break;
        case HOME:
            printFooterZ();
            break;
        case ULTIMATE:
            printFooterA();
            break;
    }
}

public void printFooterW(){
    if (calc.equals(CalcType.B))
        printW1();
    else
        printW2();
}
```

Comment: You could make License into a virtual object, and instantiate it as different subclasses based on the licensing option.  Then each subclass can know exactly what to print, corresponding to its type.  Each license probably has restrictions on what it will allow the application to do;  each subclass will then also contain trivial but useful predicates for "Am I licensed to do X?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a perfect example of where the [State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) pattern would help manage the complexity of your code, especially if you were to add other LicensingOption and CalcTypes in the future.

> This pattern is used in computer programming to encapsulate varying behavior for the same object based on its internal state. This can be a cleaner way for an object to change its behavior at runtime without resorting to large monolithic conditional statements and thus improve maintainability.

I've attached an example of an implementation of the State pattern for your case below, but please note that it's hard from your sample of code to really give you good advice (`printW1`, `printHeaderZ` and `printHeaderA` don't really give me that much information about your domain), but I did my best to give you something equivalent to the code you provided. You might want to move some of the behavior from CalcType to LicesingOption since it wasn't clear to me how those two states interact with each other in your application.

**Configuration**

```java
// Whatever way you decide to get that configuration
public CalcType calcType = Config.CalcTypen 
public LicensingOption license = Config.LicensingOption
```

**CalcType classes**

```java
abstract class CalcType {
    public void printHeader() {
        // Default behavior of printHeader() is printHeaderByLicensingOption(); 
        //  except for CalcTypeA and CalcTypeB, so we are going to redefine them in CalcTypeA and CalcTypeB.
        license.printHeaderByLicensingOption()
    }

    public void printFooter() {
        // Default behavior of printFooter() is printFooterByLicensingOption(); 
        //  except for CalcTypeA, so we are going to redefine it in CalcTypeA.
        license.printFooterByLicensingOption()
    }

    public void printFooterW() {
        // Default behavior of printFooterW() is printW2(); 
        //  except for CalcTypeB, so we are going to redefine it in CalcTypeB.
        printW2();
    }
}

class CalcTypeA extends CalcType {
    public void printHeader() {
        printHeaderX()
    }

    public void printFooter() {
        printFooterX()
    }
}

class CalcTypeB extends CalcType {
    public void printHeader() {
        printHeaderY()
    }

    public void printFooterW() {
        printW1();
    }
}
```

**LicensingOption classes**

```java
abstract class LicensingOption {
    // Those methods all have very different behaviour and it's hard from you example to know if there is any "default". 
    // Assuming there is none, just declare them abstract and define them in subclasses only.
    abstract public void printHeaderByLicensingOption();
    abstract public void printFooterByLicensingOption();
}

class ProLicense {
    public void printHeaderByLicensingOption() {
        printHeaderW();
    }

    public void printFooterByLicensingOption() {
        calcType.printFooterW()
    }
}

class HomeLicense {
    public void printHeaderByLicensingOption() {
        printHeaderZ();
    }

    public void printFooterByLicensingOption() {
        printFooterZ()
    }
}

class UltimateLicense {
    public void printHeaderByLicensingOption() {
        printHeaderA();
    }

    public void printFooterByLicensingOption() {
        printFooterA()
    }
}
```

**Note: make sure the functions you declare are virtual (default in Java, not in C++).**